# Test passes in Copado but fails deploy

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

My first test class is passing in Developer Console and in Copado but fails when I deploy. Any suggestions?

Here's the classs

```
    @isTest
private static void testFetchUser() {
    Test.startTest();
    User testUser = (User) new SObjectBuilder(User.SObjectType, 'Admin')
        .put(User.Email, 'Joe@testuser.com')
        .put(User.Username, 'joe@testuser.com.test')
        .put(User.Subsidiary_Countries__c, 'United States')
        .put(User.Primary_Subsidiary_Country__c, 'United States')
        .put(User.Routing_Group__c, 'IT')
        .createAsAdmin().getRecord();        
    User runUser = ForgotUsernameController.fetchUser('Joe@testuser.com');
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals(runUser.Username, 'joe@testuser.com.test');
}
```

And the failure message is

```
Test failure, method: ForgotUsernameControllerTest.testFetchUser -- System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: No user found with that email, Actual: joe@testuser.com.hexagonppm stack Class.ForgotUsernameControllerTest.testFetchUser: line 22, column 1
```

Comment: 2 possible causes - seealldata is true 
2nd - some configuration is different in target org.

Comment: The assertion message doesn't agree with the test class. Did you deploy that test class as well as `ForgotUserNameController`?

Comment: You were correct. Our test environment has different config. Developement is only a partial sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I found out from my admin that the Development environment is a partial sandbox and the user validations don't match. Thanks for reading this.